# HTML <meta> and <script> charset attribute

Tags: character-encoding

I am trying to understand how the charset attribute works but my charset attribute is ignored. I will add my examples.

1) I have got an HTML file with meta tag with char attribute.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Example</title>
<meta charset="windows-1254">
</head>
<body>
<p>Αποτελεί την πλέον επιτυχημένη ομάδα στην ιστορία του</p>
</body>
</html>
```

The file is saved with the option "UTF-8". However I ask the browser to show it in Turkish encoding (Windows-1254). What I show is the correct version, Greek letters are shown properly. charset="windows-1254" seems ignored

2) I have got another example with script tag. I use the JavaScript file saved with the option "UTF-8"

```
document.write("Αποτελεί την πλέον επιτυχημένη ομάδα στην ιστορία του");
```

The HTML file calling it uses  tag with charset value windows-1254. The HTML file was saved with the option ANSI, (it seems it saves it as windows-1254)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>JS Dosyası Örneği</title>
</head>
<body>
<script src="javascript.js" charset="windows-1254"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

JS file is shown correctly, charset="windows-1254" seems ignored again.

3) I have got another example with script tag. I use the JavaScript file saved with the option "UTF-8"

```
document.write("Örnek yazı");
```

The HTML file calling it uses  tag with charset value windows-1254. The HTML file was saved with the option ANSI, (it seems it saves it as windows-1254)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>JS Dosyası Örneği</title>
</head>
<body>
<script src="javascript.js" charset="windows-1254"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

JS file is shown correctly, charset="windows-1254" seems not ignored, if I delete charset="windows-1254" it works properly. I don't see an effect of charset attribute. (It doesn't sound weird, it seems IE detects the page is encoded in windows-1254 and JS file is not different)

4) The last example is from W3Schools:

http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_script_charset

If I change the charset value as advised the Greek letters aren't shown correctly in IE. It seems the charset attribute is not ignored.

The question is that "why is my attribute is ignored while the example of W3Schools not?".

Comment: What is the question? You should ask one question per post, and ask it clearly. “How charset works?” would be too broad, so try reading e.g. http://www.w3.org/International/O-charset.en.php and then perhaps asking a targeted question, if problems remain.

Comment: The question is that, "Why is the char attribute ignored in my examples?" It only depends on how I saved the file on Notepad.

Comment: If you are asking about your own test with `script`, you should remove references to `meta` and the w3schools and specify exactly how (which program, which option there) you saved the file.

Comment: I hope it is OK now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) It seems that you saved the file using Notepad. When saving a file as UTF-8, Notepad inserts a BOM (Byte Order Mark) at the start. The BOM acts as a “signature” that makes browsers treat the file as UTF-8 encoded, no matter what. This actual behavior is being documented in HTML5 (8.2.2.2 [Determining the character encoding](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/syntax.html#determining-the-character-encoding); technicality alert!). So the `meta` tag is ignored.

2) As in 1. The BOM at the start of the JS file makes browsers treat it as UTF-8 encoded. The encoding of the HTML document is not relevant here.

3) Since the JS file was saved as UTF-8 with BOM, it gets correctly processed independently of the `charset` attribute. In this simple example, the encoding of the HTML file and the information about its encoding affects only its `title` element (which may be shown outside the document proper).

4) W3schools is unreliable and confusing and should be avoided. It is not clear what they are trying to say and what they are doing, but they seem to render the test document in an `iframe` element some way. And normally the `charset` attribute matters (and does for me on that page in Firefox), when not overridden by a BOM or by HTTP headers.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. For the 3. topic, yes I save it with ANSI option but it is saved as windows-1254(Turkish). As the summary I saved the HTML file as ANSI and JS file as UTF-8. I tried both version of code: with charset="1254" in the script opening tag and without it. However for both of the situations the words are shown correctly. I couldn't experience that the charset attribute matters.

Comment: Thank you very much for your detailed explanations. Just a quick question. Is BOM only added to UTF-8 in Notepad?

Comment: @Zalajbeg, Notepad adds BOM to “Unicode” and “Unicode big endian”, too; they are in UTF-16 encoding, and the BOM is crucial there because it tells the byte order. But you don’t want to use UTF-16 on the Web. Notepad does not add BOM to “ANSI” encodings; such encodings do not even allow BOM to be represented.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is browser dependent. Using:

```
windows-1252
```

in Chrome caused no change to the Greek letters. However if you try it in IE you get:

```
Î±Î²Î³Î´ÎµÎ¶Î·Î¸
```

Comment: I was thinking the same but I have got some more experiment I will add it with an edit to my original entry.